# Exception :Configuration properties changed between Hibernate Search 5 and Hibernate Search 6

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, docker-compose, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search-6

We are getting below exception on application startup. Any reason why we are getting this?
We have already specified Hibernate Search 6 specific properties and elasticsearch 7.10?

```yaml
application.yaml  => code snippet

     search:
          enabled: true
          backend:
            type: elasticsearch
            dynamic_mapping: true
            uris: "http://xxx_elasticsearch:9200"
            
            schema_management:
              minimal_required_status: yellow
          schema_management:
            strategy: none
```

**Note**: Application is up and running for other profile.It only gives  error for the one of the profile when we used to create multi container environments on local using *docker-compose up* command

Exception :

```
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH000573: Invalid configuration passed to Hibernate Search: some properties in the given configuration are obsolete.Configuration properties changed between Hibernate Search 5 and Hibernate Search 6 Check out the reference documentation and upgrade your configuration. Obsolete properties: [hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy, hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status, hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.dynamic_mapping, hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host].","tid":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any reason why we are getting this?

It's right there in the error message:

> Configuration properties changed between Hibernate Search 5 and Hibernate Search 6

---

> We have already specified Hibernate Search 6 specific properties

That's good, but you must also remove the Hibernate Search 5 properties listed in the error message. As a safety measure, Hibernate Search 6 won't start if you leave Hibernate Search 5 configuration properties around, in case you forgot to migrate part of your configuration.

I don't see the Hibernate Search 5 properties in the snippet of configuration you gave, so I assume your snippet doesn't show everything.

Comment: Thanks for the information but we don't have any property configured specific to HS 5....application is working for other profile but not using docker-compose command

Comment: You do have properties specific to HS 5 configured. Hibernate Search doesn't invent properties, it just takes what is given to it. The properties could be set programmatically, or through `hibernate.properties`, or `application.properties`, or maybe environment variables handled by Spring Boot. But they are defined somewhere. You'll have to look for them; good luck.

Comment: Tried to find HS 5 properties in the code, hibernate.properties and application.properties file but didn't found... Is there any way to find it out?

Comment: except hibernate.dialect no other property set through programmatically.  any other way to find out which property is exactly causing the issue?