# Error creating bean with name 'costsEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search-6

We are getting exception

> Error creating bean with name 'costsEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource...Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: consolidatedCosts] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH000573: Invalid configuration passed to Hibernate Search: some properties in the given configuration are obsolete.Configuration properties changed between Hibernate Search 5 and Hibernate Search 6 Check out the reference documentation and upgrade your configuration.

Here is the code snippet

```
 @Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean costsEntityManagerFactory(
        final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        final @Qualifier("awsCostsDataSource") DataSource costsDataSource) {
    final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(
            "hibernate.dialect",
            "com.x.y.consolidatedcosts.client.xxxxxPostgresDialect");
    properties.put(
            "hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", CostsTableNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    return builder.dataSource(costsDataSource)
            .packages("com.xxx.xxx.consolidatedcosts")
            .persistenceUnit("consolidatedCosts")
            .properties(properties)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception :Configuration properties changed between Hibernate Search 5 and Hibernate Search 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73111059/exception-configuration-properties-changed-between-hibernate-search-5-and-hiber)

Comment: Nope.... is there way to print all the loaded properties before this bean creation error?

Comment: That was an automated message when reporting a duplicate question, I'm aware that didn't solve your problem. As to printing all loaded properties, no, there is no such feature as it would represent a security vulnerability (there may be passwords in those properties). You can however enter debug mode and put a breakpoint in the constructor of `org.hibernate.engine.config.internal.ConfigurationServiceImpl#ConfigurationServiceImpl`.